# Different row view in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have two rows and second row needs to be align with first row except the last element. Here is the graphical representation...

What I want:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
struct TwoRowView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<6) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
            }.padding(.bottom, 5)
            
            HStack {
                ForEach(6..<10) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to use iOS 14? If so, please check out `LazyVGrid`
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-position-views-in-a-grid-using-lazyvgrid-and-lazyhgrid

Comment: @bonkyfronk Yes brother, I am using iOS 14.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it for this particular instance.

I works by considering the second row to be an `HStack` with 3 elements, and those 3 elements are either another `HStack` with 2 elements or a single element.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<6) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
            }.padding(.bottom, 5)
            
            HStack {
                ForEach(6..<11) { i in
                    if i.isMultiple(of: 2) {
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(0..<(i == 10 ? 1 : 2)) { j in
                            Text("\(i + j)")
                                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .background(Color.red)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible approach with dynamic detection of base item width (also introduced some constants to decrease hardcoding)

Demo prepared & tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo1]

[image: demo2]

```
struct TwoRowView: View {
    let last1 = 5 // 7
    let last2 = 9 // 12
    @State private var baseWidth = CGFloat.zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<last1+1) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(GeometryReader {
                                if i == last1 {
                                  // read dynamic width once by last item
                                    Color.red
                                        .preference(key: ViewWidthKey.self, value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.width)
                                } else {
                                    Color.red
                                }
                            })

                }
            }.padding(.bottom, 5)
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewWidthKey.self) {
                self.baseWidth = $0
            }

            HStack {
                ForEach(6..<last2+1) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .frame(maxWidth: i == last2 ? .infinity : self.baseWidth )
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct ViewWidthKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```